# How to solve system of equations with variables $t[1],...,t[n]$

Tags: equation-solving

I procedurally generated a set of equations

$f_1(t[1],t[2],...,t[n]) = 0,...,f_n(t[1],t[2],...,t[n]) = 0.$

Since I want this type of system of equations for any integer $n$, I defined by variable to be $\{t[1],...,t[n]\}$. But this cause problem when I tried to solve for them using:

```
Solve[{f_1(t[1],t[2],...,t[n]),...,f_n(t[1],t[2],...,t[n])} == 0,{t[1],...,t[n]}].
```

The output is simply

```
{}
```

How do I go about making Mathematica solve this type of equations for any $n$?

Comment: If $n$ is not explicitly an integer, then *Mathematica* is not yet equipped to deal with such arbitrary-dimension problems.

Comment: I mean, before I solve an equation I would set $n$ to a specific number e.g. $n = 4$. Mathematica would solve it if I were to use t1,t2,t3,t4 as variables. Is there a way to name variables systematically like that so I don't need to use t[1],t[2],t[3],t[4]? Thank you.

Comment: You can use Array[t, 4]

Comment: You cannot use underscore in a varoable name. This has a different meaning in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

### Errors

Your expression

```
Solve[{f_1(t[1],t[2],...,t[n]),...,f_n(t[1],t[2],...,t[n])} == 0,{t[1],...,t[n]}].
```

is not valid syntax in *Mathematica* for what you need.

- `_` or `Blank[]` is a pattern object that can stand for any Wolfram
  Language expression.
- Function arguments are in square brackets, `f[x]` not `f(x)`.
- `.` or `Dot` gives products of vectors, matrices, and tensors.

### Answer

There is NO problem with generating equations and using [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) programmatically. If the answer is `{}` implied that you system doesn't have a solution. Here some random equations that may have solutions sometimes.

```
Solve[
 Table[
  Sum[t[RandomInteger[4]] RandomInteger[9], {3}] == 0
  , {3}
  ]
 , Array[t, 4]
 ]
(* {{t[2] -> -((4 t[0])/187) - (63 t[1])/187, 
  t[3] -> (36 t[0])/187 + (6 t[1])/187, 
  t[4] -> -((120 t[0])/187) + (147 t[1])/374}} *)
```